# wildfly localhost content is outdated

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I started having an issue after I updated my project in eclipse with svn. The server seems to run with no errors and the localhost shows the content. However it's outdated and changes in some html for example are not shown. I tryed to clear history on the browsers etc but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas??Thanks!

Comment: Try right clicking into the server on eclipse and select Full Publish. Also check if the Build Automatically option is checked on eclipse. If the answer is No, you'll have to build the project before.

Comment: There is no such option ( full publish ). There is an option publish show which doesn't seem to solve the problem. Also Build Automatically is checked. Still no change is localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to make some changes on the server. From eclipse right click on the server and select add and remove then add all the resources from the available section. Also check the option "if server is started, publish changes immediately"